# 'Structure theorem' of abelian group $k$-schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

Suppose $G$ is a finite etale abelian group scheme over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero, and $X$ is a smooth geometrically integral $k$-variety. If I want to compute the structure of the etale cohomology groups $H^q(X,G)$, can I first 'decompose' $G$ in the usual abelian group [structure theorem](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_abelian_groups#:%7E:text=The%20structure%20theorem%20for%20finitely,of%20finitely%20many%20cyclic%20groups) style, $$G \cong \mathbb{Z}^r \oplus \sum _{i = 1}^s \mu_{n_i}$$ where $n_i$ divides $n_{i+1}$ for $i \in \{1,2,...,n-1\}$?

In this case, is $\mathbb{Z}$ the constant group scheme? I am able to easily compute $H^q(X,\mu_{n_i})$ for each $q$, and can we then say $$H^q(X,G) \cong \bigoplus _{i=1} ^r H^q(X,\mathbb{Z}) \oplus H^q(X,\mu_{n_1}) \oplus ... \oplus H^q(X,\mu_{n_s}),$$ where the first term is $r$ copies of $H^q(X,\mathbb{Z})$ (to be evaluated)?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't finite so the first term doesn't appear. Other than that, with your hypotheses $G$ is constant, so I would write it as a direct sum of finite cyclic groups (which are isomorphic to the $\mu_n$ in this case).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan But you answered my other question yesterday and clarified that *finite* means $G \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\, k$ is finite, not $G$ looking like a finite group (scheme). Anyhow, is $G$ actually acting as a constant group scheme? Say, if $q=1$, then we're looking at $G$-covers of $X$, no? Sorry if the question(s) are confusing, I can attempt to clarify if needed.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Also, I thought that $H^q(-,\mu_n)$ are the derived functors of the group scheme $\mu_{n,k}$, sending a scheme $T$ to its elements of order $n$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said, and if you write down what the constant group scheme with constant value $A$ is, you'll find that it's finite in the above sense iff $A$ is finite in the usual sense. So the constant group scheme with value $\mathbb{Z}$ is not finite and doesn't occur here. What's the relevance of your second question to what I said?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Because I'm thinking if $G$ is a constant group scheme (which it is), then its decomposition in the above sense must be into constant group schemes too. But the multiplicative group schemes $\mu_n$ doesn't work that way.

Comment: Over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero (which you stipulated in your question), $\mu_n$ is constant and isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Check this!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ok I will, thank you. So I suppose we should have $$H^q(X,G) \cong \bigoplus _{i = 1} ^s H^q(X, \underline{\mathbb{Z}/n_i\mathbb{Z}}),$$ where $n_i |n_{i+1}$?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know anyway.